# Basic question on the dimension of affine varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose I have an affine variety defined by some polynomials
$f_1(x_1, ..., x_n), ..., f_r(x_1, ..., x_n)$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$, and suppose this has dimension $L$. We can also view the polynomials as sitting inside $\mathbb{C}[x_1, ..., x_n, y_1, ..., y_r]$ so it produces an affine variety inside $\mathbb{C}^{n + r}$. I mean they are really the ``same", so does the two (the one sitting inside $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $\mathbb{C}^{n + r}$) have the same dimension?

Comment: I had a question that might be related to this, so I'm just trying to understand.
Are the variables $y_1, \ldots, y_r$ related to the polynomials $f_1, \ldots, f_r$ in some way? Or is it just a coincidence that you used $r$ in both cases?

Comment: It was by mistake that I used $r$ for both, they are not related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The variety corresponding to the ideal $I = (f_1, \dots, f_r) $ in $\mathbb C^{n+r}$ will be $X \times \mathbb C^r$, where $X$ is the zero set of $I$ in $\mathbb C^n$.

Comment: I see. So the dimension will be $L+r$ then?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.